# Twitter Stream response for key words

Tags: python, twitter

i have small python program to extract tweets from twitter stream for keywords.
want to link the keyword with received  tweets.how can i do that in python efficiently.
I may have more than 200 keys.
eg:
keywords = "key1,key2,key3"
received 4 tweets and i want to directly link incoming text and key..
like below
1)tweets msgs key1 tweets tweets text --> key1
2)tweets msgs key2 tweets tweets text --> key2
3)tweets msgs key3 tweets tweets text --> key3
4)tweets msgs key1 tweets tweets text --> key1

**Update:**
Currently am using **for loop to iterate the key list** and use **find** to see if the key is present in the tweet text.But i feel there should be better and efficient way of doing this in python.

```
 for title in title_list:
     if tweet_lower.find(title) != -1:
        setattr(status, 'title',title)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict` from [Python's collection module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html).

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: tweet_keyword_storage = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: tweet_keyword_storage['key1'].append('tweets msgs key1 tweets tweets text')

In [4]: tweet_keyword_storage['key2'].append('tweets msgs key2 tweets tweets text')

In [5]: tweet_keyword_storage['key3'].append('tweets msgs key3 tweets tweets text')

In [6]: tweet_keyword_storage['key1'].append('tweets msgs key1 tweets tweets text')

In [7]: print tweet_keyword_storage
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key3': ['tweets msgs key3 tweets tweets text'], 'key2': ['tweets msgs key2 tweets tweets text'], 'key1': ['tweets msgs key1 tweets tweets text', 'tweets msgs key1 tweets tweets text']})
```

Comment: thanks for the replay.But my requirement is bit different.I expressed my requirement wrongly.here what i want. I receive lot of tweets but i dont know which tweets belongs to which key.So i need a program to map incoming tweets with the list of keywords.i have a for loop which loops through my key words and   check for occurrence of keyword in the text.This is inefficient.So pls  help me with any link or idea about how i can do this in python way.(Am a java developer,now learning python)